# I have made a program to print out 'letters' formed using the asterisk. I have a lot of lines of code. Is there a better way to do this?

Tags: python-3.x

I have been learning Python for two months and just hacking at trying to come up with a good solution for this.

I'm really only working with the built-in functions thus far. (Obviously, right?!)

I've shown examples of the output at the top above the code itself.

My first version of this had a function for each required line of print. I switched to dictionary and that removed over 100 lines of code :).

I'm curious if there is a better approach to this problem. Thanks.

```
 ***
*   *
*   *
*****
*   *
*   *
*   *

****
*   *
*   *
*   *
*****
*   *
*   *
*   *
****

 ****
*
*
*
*
*
*
 ****



# A program to print out letters using a user-input string

letter_component_dict = {
    "s_three": " ***", "one_sss_one": "*   *", "one_ssss_one": "*    *", "one_sssss_one": "*     *",
    "five": "*****", "six": "******", "four": "****", "s_four": " ****", "ss_one": "  *", "one": "*",
    "one_sss_two": "*   **", "s_five": " *****", "sss_one": "   *", "one_s_one": "* *", "two": "**",
    "s_two": " **", "two_sss_two": "**   **", "one_s_one_s_one_s_one": "* * * *", "one_ss_one_ss_one": "*  *  *",
    "two_ssss_one": "**    *", "one_s_one_sss_one": "* *   *", "one_sss_one_s_one": "*   * *",
    "one_ssss_two": "*    **", "one_ss_one_s_one": "*  * *", "ssssss_one": "      *", "sssss_one": "     *",
    "s_one_sss_one": " *   *", "ss_one_s_one": "  * *", "one_sssssss_one": "*       *",
    "s_one_s_one_s_one_s_one": " * * * *", "one_sss_one_sss_one": "*   *   *", "ss_one_sss_one": "  *   *",
    "sss_one_s_one": "   * *", "s_one_sssss_one": " *     *", "ssss_one": "    *", "s_one": " *",
    "one_ss_one": "*  *"
}


# Functions to draw letters
def a():
    print(letter_component_dict["s_three"])
    for i in range(2):
        print(letter_component_dict["one_sss_one"])
    print(letter_component_dict["five"])
    for i in range(3):
        print(letter_component_dict["one_sss_one"])
    print()


def b():
    print(letter_component_dict["four"])
    for i in range(3):
        print(letter_component_dict["one_sss_one"])
    print(letter_component_dict["five"])
    for i in range(3):
        print(letter_component_dict["one_sss_one"])
    print(letter_component_dict["four"])
    print()


def c():
    print(letter_component_dict["s_four"])
    for i in range(6):
        print(letter_component_dict["one"])
    print(letter_component_dict["s_four"])
    print()


def d():
    print(letter_component_dict["four"])
    for i in range(6):
        print(letter_component_dict["one_sss_one"])
    print(letter_component_dict["four"])
    print()


def e():
    print(letter_component_dict["five"])
    for i in range(3):
        print(letter_component_dict["one"])
    print(letter_component_dict["four"])
    for i in range(3):
        print(letter_component_dict["one"])
    print(letter_component_dict["five"])
    print()


def f():
    print(letter_component_dict["five"])
    for i in range(3):
        print(letter_component_dict["one"])
    print(letter_component_dict["four"])
    for i in range(4):
        print(letter_component_dict["one"])
    print()


def g():
    print(letter_component_dict["s_four"])
    for i in range(3):
        print(letter_component_dict["one"])
    print(letter_component_dict["one_sss_two"])
    for i in range(3):
        print(letter_component_dict["one_ssss_one"])
    print(letter_component_dict["s_four"])
    print()


def h():
    for i in range(4):
        print(letter_component_dict["one_ssss_one"])
    print(letter_component_dict["six"])
    for i in range(4):
        print(letter_component_dict["one_ssss_one"])
    print()


def i():
    print(letter_component_dict["five"])
    for i in range(6):
        print(letter_component_dict["ss_one"])
    print(letter_component_dict["five"])
    print()


def j():
    print(letter_component_dict["s_five"])
    for i in range(5):
        print(letter_component_dict["sss_one"])
    print(letter_component_dict["one_ss_one"]) # one_ss_one
    print(letter_component_dict["s_two"])
    print()


def k():
    print(letter_component_dict["one_ssss_one"])
    print(letter_component_dict["one_sss_one"])
    print(letter_component_dict["one_s_one"])
    print(letter_component_dict["two"])
    print(letter_component_dict["one_s_one"])
    print(letter_component_dict["one_sss_one"])
    print(letter_component_dict["one_ssss_one"])
    print()


def l():
    for i in range(7):
        print(letter_component_dict["one"])
    print(letter_component_dict["six"])
    print()


def m():
    print(letter_component_dict["one_sssss_one"])
    print(letter_component_dict["two_sss_two"])
    print(letter_component_dict["one_s_one_s_one_s_one"])
    print(letter_component_dict["one_ss_one_ss_one"])
    for i in range(4):
        print(letter_component_dict["one_sssss_one"])
    print()


def n():
    print(letter_component_dict["one_sssss_one"])
    print(letter_component_dict["two_ssss_one"])
    print(letter_component_dict["one_s_one_sss_one"])
    print(letter_component_dict["one_ss_one_ss_one"])
    print(letter_component_dict["one_sss_one_s_one"])
    print(letter_component_dict["one_ssss_two"])
    print(letter_component_dict["one_sssss_one"])
    print()


def o():
    print(letter_component_dict["s_five"])
    for i in range(6):
        print(letter_component_dict["one_sssss_one"])
    print(letter_component_dict["s_five"])
    print()


def p():
    print(letter_component_dict["six"])
    for i in range(3):
        print(letter_component_dict["one_ssss_one"])
    print(letter_component_dict["six"])
    for i in range(4):
        print(letter_component_dict["one"])
    print()


def q():
    print(letter_component_dict["six"])
    for i in range(5):
        print(letter_component_dict["one_ssss_one"])
    print(letter_component_dict["one_ss_one_s_one"])
    print(letter_component_dict["six"])
    print(letter_component_dict["ssssss_one"])
    print()


def r():
    print(letter_component_dict["six"])
    for i in range(3):
        print(letter_component_dict["one_ssss_one"])
    print(letter_component_dict["five"])
    print(letter_component_dict["one_sss_one"])
    print(letter_component_dict["one_ssss_one"])
    print(letter_component_dict["one_sssss_one"])
    print()


def s():
    print(letter_component_dict["s_five"])
    for i in range(3):
        print(letter_component_dict["one"])
    print(letter_component_dict["s_four"])
    for i in range(3):
        print(letter_component_dict["sssss_one"])
    print(letter_component_dict["five"])
    print()


def t():
    print(letter_component_dict["five"])
    for i in range(7):
        print(letter_component_dict["ss_one"])
    print()


def u():
    for i in range(7):
        print(letter_component_dict["one_ssss_one"])
    print(letter_component_dict["s_four"])
    print()


def v():
    for i in range(3):
        print(letter_component_dict["one_sssss_one"])
    for i in range(3):
        print(letter_component_dict["s_one_sss_one"])
    for i in range(3):
        print(letter_component_dict["ss_one_s_one"])
    print(letter_component_dict["sss_one"])
    print()


def w():
    for i in range(4):
        print(letter_component_dict["one_sssssss_one"])
    for i in range(3):
        print(letter_component_dict["one_sss_one_sss_one"])
    print(letter_component_dict["s_one_s_one_s_one_s_one"])
    print(letter_component_dict["ss_one_sss_one"])
    print()


def x():
    print(letter_component_dict["one_sssssss_one"])
    print(letter_component_dict["s_one_sssss_one"])
    print(letter_component_dict["ss_one_sss_one"])
    print(letter_component_dict["sss_one_s_one"])
    print(letter_component_dict["ssss_one"])
    print(letter_component_dict["sss_one_s_one"])
    print(letter_component_dict["ss_one_sss_one"])
    print(letter_component_dict["s_one_sssss_one"])
    print(letter_component_dict["one_sssssss_one"])
    print()


def y():
    for i in range(3):
        print(letter_component_dict["one_sssss_one"])
    print(letter_component_dict["s_one_sss_one"])
    print(letter_component_dict["ss_one_s_one"])
    for i in range(5):
        print(letter_component_dict["sss_one"])
    print()


def z():
    print(letter_component_dict["six"])
    print(letter_component_dict["ssss_one"])
    print(letter_component_dict["sss_one"])
    for i in range(3):
        print(letter_component_dict["ss_one"])
    print(letter_component_dict["s_one"])
    print(letter_component_dict["one"])
    print(letter_component_dict["six"])




raw_input = input("Type a word: ")

for letter in raw_input:
    eval(letter.lower() + "()")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure. In a perfect world you would never write the same statement more than once. Lets see if we can modularize your existing code so that it can be adapted to the necessary requirements.

So, while it is a good improvement on redundancy to use the dictionary, it is a bit repetitive to have one function for each letter. We know what each letter looks like so why not store the whole letter in a dictionary. This way we can take away the whole `a() b() c() ... z()` collection.

Now, I did not complete the whole revision but here is a working example for `a` and `b`.

```
letters = {'a':" ***\n*   *\n*   *\n*****\n*   *\n*   *\n*   *",
            'b': "****\n*   *\n*   *\n*   *\n*****\n*   *\n*   *\n*   *"
            }

raw_input = input("Type a word: ")

for letter in raw_input:
    print(letters[letter.lower()])
```

As you can see, the `letters` dictionary contain the definition for `a` and `b`, no more. then we just print the value for those keys. You still need to input the rest of the alphabet, but it will now be <50 lines of code.